# Change owner through graphical interface in standard Ubuntu (with Gnome Shell)

Tags: gnome, permissions, nautilus, ownership

Users can be confronted with the need to change ownership of a drive. One obviously can use the terminal, but **is there currently a supported way to change ownership using a graphical tool in Ubuntu with Gnome Shell?**

I regularly see questions of users on how to do that (e.g. after reformatting their drive to the ext4 file system), and I hate to have to recommend them to use `sudo -H nautilus`. 1) It is not a proper way to run graphical applications as root ; 2) modern trends are never to run the graphical applications as such as root (for example, "Disks" application).

We used to be able to run `gksudo nautilus`, which allowed to run nautilus as root without the risk of breaking user configuration. We do not have `gksudo` anymore. Instead, there is `pkexec`, but Ubuntu does not come with a policy file in place. So this option is not out of the box available to users.

The officially supported way to perform root actions with graphical tools such as `nautilus` and `gedit` is to use the "admin://" URI. With the command

```
nautilus admin://
```

one can open nautilus and perform actions that require root permissions. As such, one can change permissions of files from a different owner. However, **the properties dialog does not allow to change the user** of a file or directory.

Hence the question: "is there currently a supported way to change ownership using a graphical tool in Ubuntu with Gnome Shell?".